# MariaDB - Changing explicit_defaults_to_timestamp

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to check from MariaDB docs online how I can turn ON `explicit_defaults_to_timestamp` global variable. I encountered this as part of Apache Airflow db setup.

Is there any solution to do this? I am running mysql as system service via `systemctl`.

Comment: What version are you using?  (`TIMESTAMP` defaulting changed not too long ago.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open you `my.conf/ini`

find the section `[mysqld]`

and add `explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = 1`

sometimes you need instead

`explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = ON`

You can check after restarting mysql with
`SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%timestamp%';` if it is enabled

But this is a not standard option and could be removed at some point

Answer (score 0):

To add to @nbk answer. I had to change it on `/etc/my.cnf.d/mariadb-server.cnf` and it was explicit_defaults_for_timestamp=ON`